# Code yields different results when iterating through for loops versus running once

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I wrote a script which edits a .txt file of a simulation program (LTspice) and then runs the simulation using the modified .txt file.

There are eight values (with three possible states) which I want to change independently for each iteration. Therefore I used eight for loops to iterate through all the combinations by searching and replacing the strings in the .txt file. This looks like this:

```
Txt_original = 'SIM_COM_Automated_Copy.txt' #LTSpice output file has to be copied manually first

rawDataFile = 'SIM_COM_Automated_Copy.raw'

list1 =[]
list2 = []

with open(Txt_original, 'rb') as file:
        Data_backup = file.read()

resistorValues = [['Res1=1980', 'Res1=2000', 'Res1=2020'],['Res2=1980', 'Res2=2000', 'Res2=2020'], ['Res3=1980', 'Res3=2000', 'Res3=2020'], ['Res4=1980', 'Res4=2000', 'Res4=2020'], ['Res7=19800', 'Res7=20000', 'Res7=20200'], ['Res8=9900', 'Res8=10000', 'Res8=10100'], ['Res16=19800', 'Res16=20000', 'Res16=20200'], ['Res17=9900', 'Res17=10000', 'Res17=10100']] 

count = 0

for a in range(1,3):
    editSimParameters(Txt_original, resistorValues[0][0], resistorValues[0][a] ) #Res1
    for b in range(1,3):
        editSimParameters(Txt_original, resistorValues[1][0], resistorValues[1][b] ) #Res2
        for c in range(1,3):
            editSimParameters(Txt_original, resistorValues[2][0], resistorValues[2][c] ) #Res3
            for d in range(1,3):
                editSimParameters(Txt_original, resistorValues[3][0], resistorValues[3][d] ) #Res4
                for e in range(1,2):
                    editSimParameters(Txt_original, resistorValues[4][0], resistorValues[4][e] ) #Res7
                    for f in range(1,2):
                        editSimParameters(Txt_original, resistorValues[5][0], resistorValues[5][f] ) #Res8
                        for g in range(1,2):
                            editSimParameters(Txt_original, resistorValues[6][0], resistorValues[6][g] ) #Res16
                            for h in range(1,2):
                                editSimParameters(Txt_original, resistorValues[7][0], resistorValues[7][h] ) #Res17
                                runSimulation(Txt_original)
                                #time.sleep(10)
                                result = evaluateResults(rawDataFile)
                                valueSet = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
                                
                                if valueSet == [2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1]:
                                    print('Res1= '+resistorValues[0][a])
                                    print('Res2= '+resistorValues[1][b])
                                    print('Res3= '+resistorValues[2][c])
                                    print('Res4= '+resistorValues[3][d])
                                    print('Res7= '+resistorValues[4][e])
                                    print('Res8= '+resistorValues[5][f])
                                    print('Res16= '+resistorValues[6][g])
                                    print('Res17= '+resistorValues[7][h])
                                    print('The result of the combination ' + str(valueSet) + ' is ' + str(result))
                                
                                list1.append(result)
                                list2.append(valueSet)

                                    
                                with open(Txt_original, 'wb') as file:  #Reset the working file
                                    file.write(Data_backup)
                                
                                #Progress Tracking
                                count = count +1        

                                if count%25 == 0:
                                    print(count)
```

The editSimParameters() function looks like this:

```
def editSimParameters(workingFile, oldParam, newParam):
    with open(workingFile, 'rb') as file:
        Data_original = file.read() 
        Data_temp = Data_original.replace(oldParam.encode('utf-8'), newParam.encode('utf-8'))
    
    with open(workingFile, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(Data_temp)
```

I have reduced the number of loop iteration in this example, so that the code terminates faster. Nonetheless when running this code the result for the combination [2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1] is different to the result of the same combination which I obtained by altering the for loops, so that only this combination is executed:

Result after the iteration (16 simulations in total): The result of the combination [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1] is 16.347881

Result with altered for loops (1 simulation): The result of the combination [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1] is 16.327114

The result with just one simulation is correct which I verified by doing the simulation manually.

Am I overseeing a problem when iterating over and changing the .txt file or is there anything else?

Comment: Holy nesting batman.

Comment: I think you would be better off reading the "template file" once and emitting modified versions of it. Given the structure of your code as it is, it's getting hard to find where the bug, if any, is...

Comment: Please check that you do not do something like 
 `"1234".replace("1","2").replace("2","3").replace("3","4").replace("4","5")` and want to get "2345" from it ... because if will be "5555".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a much simplified (and more powerful) version of what you seem to be trying to do, using `itertools.product` and a regular expression to replace the resistor values.

The idea is that we

- read your original LTSpice file (which I don't have at hand, hence a string constant in the source)
- set up a dictionary matching resistor names to the values those resistors should be attempted with
- use some gentle `zip` magic to massage that dictionary into a form `itertools.product` accepts
- use `itertools.product` to generate the cartesian product of the values, then `zip` them back with the keys to get a `combo` dict
- loop over the combo and use `re.sub` to substitute those values into (a copy of) the template.
- Instead of `print()`ing the `data` like we do here, you'd write that out to the file you feed to the simulator, and do what you must there. **I would recommend not overwriting the original template file.**

You can add as many keys and values to the `resistor_combos` dict as you like, and they'll all be exhaustively checked.

```
import itertools
import re

# Would be read from the original SIM_COM_Automated_Copy file
template = """
Res1=100
Res2=100
Res8=1000
""".strip()

resistor_combos = {
    "Res1": [123, 456],
    "Res2": [789, 126],
}

resistor_keys, resistor_values = zip(*resistor_combos.items())

for value_combo in itertools.product(*resistor_values):
    combo = dict(zip(resistor_keys, value_combo))
    data = template  # "Copy" the template for modification
    for key, value in combo.items():
        data = re.sub(f"^{key}=(\d+)", f"{key}={value}", data, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    print(combo)
    print(data)
    print("====")
```

This prints out

```
{'Res1': 123, 'Res2': 789}
Res1=123
Res2=789
Res8=1000
====
{'Res1': 123, 'Res2': 126}
Res1=123
Res2=126
Res8=1000
====
{'Res1': 456, 'Res2': 789}
Res1=456
Res2=789
Res8=1000
====
{'Res1': 456, 'Res2': 126}
Res1=456
Res2=126
Res8=1000
====
```